# Avalonia DataGrid looks empty until sorted

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid, avaloniaui

I am using AvaloniaUI 11.0.0-preview7, .NET 7, MVVM Community Toolkit.

When instanciating a `DataGrid` and binding the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection`, it appears empty until I sort a column.

View:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Binding="{Binding Index}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
    [...]
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<LineViewModel> Lines { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel() {
        _lineViewModel = new LineViewModel();
        Lines = new ObservableCollection<LineViewModel>() {_lineViewModel };
    }

    private LineViewModel _lineViewModel;
}

public partial class LineViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public LineViewModel()
    {
        Option = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Foo", "Bar" };
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _index;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Option { get; set; }
}
```

I don't see what I'm doing differently from online resources, nor what could cause this behavior.
Debugging the `Lines` getter confirms it is called once, and is initialized with one `LineViewModel` item before that happens.

I have created a sample project that isolates the issue: https://github.com/JulienBernard3383279/AvaloniaPad

Why does the data grid initially appear empty ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused because I had the DataGrid inside a StackPanel and somehow it didn't resize the DataGrid when a item was added. Setting the Height seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this issue when looking at a similar issue.

[JellyO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76308623/8393321)s comment fixed the issue. But I did not want to explicitely set the height.

So I played around a bit and want to share the results just in case someone else does not want to set the height explicitely.

## Problem:

When having a `DataGrid` inside a `StackPanel` with Oriention set to Vertical, inside a TabControl, initially the DataGrid appears empty.

Upon resizing the window, it is fixed.
Upon switching Tabs in the TabControl it is fixed.
But: When switching from a Tab where the Table contains 1 Item to one Tab where the table should have 2 items, only 1 Item will be shown.

## What I learned from playing around

#### Learning 1: StackPanel Orientation

It seems like this issue only occurs when `StackPanel.Orientation` is set to `Vertical`.

#### Learning 2: If vertical, the nesting does not matter

I've tried multiple nesting depths and nesting constellation. The issue persists, if on any level above the DataGrid, there is a `StackPanel` with orientation `Vertical`

#### Learning 3: DockPanels

This issue also occurs when the DataGrid is in a `DockPanel`, but only if the `DataGrid` uses the `DockPanel.Dock` property. If that is set to no matter what. The issue is observable.

## Solution:

Other than setting the Height explicitely (which seems to be the recommended thing to do for a DataGrid (sorry, I did not save the source for that)), one can set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` on the DataGrid.

I have no idea why it does that, but that fixes it, without setting a specific height. This for some reason does not show a vertical scrollbar whatsoever. But I am an avalonia (and MVVM and UI programming for that matter) noob and have no idea what I am doing. So that might be on me.